# How do I select segments of a matrix based on values in a CSV within a loop (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a 250 24min wav files. For each file I have a random 30sec period which I want to pull out for analysis. The start times and end times for each 30 sec period is in a CSV.
I want to create a loop that reads in the audiofile, extracts the 30 sec period from the file, analyzes and repears. E.g., Read in file_one, downselect file_one wav to samples in row one of the CSV. Read in file_two, downselct file_two to samples in row two of the csv. Etc.

I am at a loss on how to do this. Working code below:

```
M = csvread(segments.csv) % 2 columns, 280 rows

for i = 31:3527
    [y,Fs] = audioread(strcat(DirIn,'/',filelist(i).name)); % read in wav file
    z = y([Col 1, Row i+31:Col 2, Row i+31], [1]) % Need help here
    snips_db = 20*log10(z) - Sensitivity - Gain 
    c(end+1;) = snips_db
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a total rookie at this.

**EDIT**

I think I have found a solution. Would be happy if anyone had critiques of the following code. The i x:x line establishes the specific range of files (in this case 3-4 of 50 wav files in folder.

```
Dirin = 'C:\Users\Benjamin Colbert\Desktop\New folder'
allfiles=dir('C:\Users\Benjamin Colbert\Desktop\New folder\*.wav');
filelist={allfiles.name};
db = [];
D = cell(i,1);
C = csvread("start_end.csv")

for i = 3:4
    [y,Fs] = audioread(char(strcat(Dirin,"\",filelist(1)))); % read in wav file
    z = y(C(i,1):C(i,2)) % Need help here
    z = rms(z)
    snips_db = 20*log10(z) - Sensitivity - Gain 
    D{i} = snips_db;
end

M = vertcat(D{:}); %Final array of all values
```

Comment: It would be good if you can add some more detail about the data structures you have. How does the length of `M` (280) relate to the values of `i` you are using? Does `M` contain the index you want to extract, or the timepoint? If `M` contains the index, you could try something like `z = y( M(i+31,1) : M(i+31,2) , :)`. If that doesn't work, I think you will need to add some more details to your question. P.S. a good thing to think about when approaching these problems is to notice the fact that you have not actually used `M` in your for loop!

Comment: @magnesium I made some edits in original post. Would like any input.